# Get a json response in Jsp

Tags: json, google-api

I am working with Google Calender Api.When i try to fetch all attendees for that meeting or event using event.getAttendees();

I get the following Json Response.
How to get value of Displayname in jsp

```
[
  {"displayName":"Abc"
   "email":"abc@gmail.com",
   "organizer":true,
   "responseStatus":"accepted",
   "self":true}
   , 
   { 
      "displsyName" :"Test"
     "email":"test@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus":"needsAction"}]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a json java lib for this. Jackson is a very good one. Check this: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

It builds a bean from the json string automatically for you.
Google has a similar lib called Gson, but it is less popular IMO. It may already be in your stack if you use google api libs.